# Quarkus, Flyway can't connect to TestContainer postgresql

Tags: postgresql, quarkus, flyway

I'm working on setting up Flyway in my quarkus app that already has appropriate database setup, works fine but does the hand-done db setup (`initdb()`) method to setup its database.

I currently test using a postgresql testcontainer instance to test against, and set it up in the following way:

```java
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        log.info("STARTING test lifecycle resources.");
        Map<String, String> configOverride = new HashMap<>();

        if(MYSQL_CONTAINER == null || !MYSQL_CONTAINER.isRunning()){
            PostgreSQLContainerProvider provider = new PostgreSQLContainerProvider();
            MYSQL_CONTAINER = provider.newInstance();
            MYSQL_CONTAINER.withDatabaseName("client-demo");
            MYSQL_CONTAINER.start();
        }
        configOverride.put("quarkus.datasource.db-kind", "postgresql");
        configOverride.put("quarkus.datasource.username", MYSQL_CONTAINER.getUsername());
        configOverride.put("quarkus.datasource.password", MYSQL_CONTAINER.getPassword());
        // replaceFirst required to connect; invalidUri exception thrown otherwise
        configOverride.put("quarkus.datasource.reactive.url", MYSQL_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl().replaceFirst("jdbc:", ""));

        log.info("Config overrides: {}", configOverride);
        return configOverride;
    }
```

This has worked fine thusfar, and the test code can appropriately interact with the database as expected.

However, when I try to add Flyway to the equation, it seems that Flyway can't connect to the database:

```
2022-01-25 14:23:03,005 INFO  [org.acm.cus.dem.uti.TestResourceLifecycleManager] (pool-4-thread-1) Config overrides: {quarkus.datasource.password=test, quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql, quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://localhost:49352/client-demo?loggerLevel=OFF, quarkus.datasource.username=test}
2022-01-25 14:23:03,695 WARN  [io.agr.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': FATAL: password authentication failed for user "test"
2022-01-25 14:23:03,721 INFO  [org.acm.cus.dem.uti.TestResourceLifecycleManager] (main) STOPPING test lifecycle resources.
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.251 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.acme.cust.demo.CucumberTest
[ERROR] org.acme.cust.demo.CucumberTest.getTests  Time elapsed: 15.238 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "test"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config you mention a reactive database connection. But Flyway still needs the „old“ jdbc connection. So you probably have to configure both, if you still want to use the db the reactive way.

Comment: Configure both? Looks to me like the same config is used for both. I have also used the `quarkus.datasource.jdbc=true` config (and took out the bit where I remove `jbdc:` from the url), with no effect

Comment: Do you configure quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url?

Comment: A short background: We also connected the reactive db connection. But for Flyway we still ned the jdbc configuration as mentioned in https://quarkus.io/guides/flyway . At least that was in Quarkus 1.11 the way we got it running.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that config as an option (could have just missed it). Thanks, it seems to get past the auth, but now it's throwing an error about the postgresql version in the test container. Looking into it, and probably a topic for another question

Comment: Nice! Yes, that‘s a new question. And unfortunately I don‘t know about supported Postgres versions. We are still around 10 or maybe 11.

Comment: Yeah according to the error, the test container is serving 9.6; "No longer supported" lol thanks again!